# How to find clients beyond sites like oDesk/Guru/Freelancer?

Tags: freelance-websites, attracting-clients, marketing, growth

I have been freelancing for more than a year now. It's been great in terms that I get paid decent amount for hours I have put in. My issue is I'd like to diversify risk and find new clients beyond these online sites.

My freelancing work has all come from oDesk, Guru, or Freelancer. How can I find clients outside the freelancing sites?

Comment: I think this is a near-duplicate of another question, but not sure how to mark your question as such. And I'm struggling to see how this question could be answered definitively. It would seem to invite debate, and such questions are generally considered a poor fit for SE communities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the first client](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/56/finding-the-first-client). As well, this feels as though it is not constructive, in that it would invite debate and lists

Comment: Hi Sidharth, the way your question is worded currently invites open-ended discussion rather than answers backed by facts, references and specific expertise. I made a suggested edit that focuses on the question you put in the title. This should help make it more clear what you're looking for. Also, you should check out the duplicate Luke linked to. If it doesn't answer your question, I suggest editing further to clarify the differences. Good luck! :)

Comment: I have some insight on the answer to the question because I could have asked a similar question when I look at how I have also been working the last 16 years. This is a very valid question as it stands. The answers will be around marketing one's self or setting up the business from sole-propriter to limited liability company. I will also propose an edit. So I can share my experience with those who need it. I doubt there can be debating when there are very specific things you have to do to be successful outside the scope of these online sites.

Comment: One should definitely read this reply: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/2848/517 . It's also a reply to this questions, more or less.