# How to build up long-term clients

Tags: attracting-clients, pay-rate

I have been making website as a hobby since the late 90´s, I have been working as a front-end developer between 2013 to 2014. I have finished a 1 year program at University in the subject of Web Development. I am currently on my first year on a 3 year program at University on the subject of becoming a Full-Stack Developer. I also have some experience from smaller freelancing job in the past.

When I am done with my studies I would like to freelance as a Web Developer. I need to work as freelancer since there is no work as a Web Developer where I live. After my studies I would need to charge at least $50/h (50% goes to taxes as a self-employed person in Sweden).

Since I already have a lot of experience, I only need to spend around 2-3 hours per day on my studies. I also have all the money I need for my living expenses as long as I'm at University.

So I think I have a great opportunity to start my Freelancing Career now, since I both have the money I need for my living and around 8 hours free-time for the next 2.5 years.

I already have one client (rate $50/h) at UpWork who keeps coming back to me every now and then.

So, now I want to start freelancing, but not for the reason to make money,  for the reason to build up clients that keeps coming back. Once I finish at University, I will be able to "just start freelancing".

As I see it there is two ways to do this:

1. Start trying to fill my schedule with 10$/h work, and once it is filled higher the rate with 5$ and keep doing so until I reach 50$/h. So I at the same time build a lot of references and "reviews" at sites like UpWork.

or

2. Start trying to fill my schedule with $50/h work from the start, even if it does not fill up my schedule at the beginning.

I really want to invest the time I have in the best way possible, So I don't want to go for the wrong one (1 or 2).

Which way would be best trying to build up clients, and future work? Or is there a better way that I haven't been thinking of?

Answer (score 7):

- **Good** clients are generally *not* the clients looking for the *cheapest* workers they can find. They are customarily more vested in abilities than actual price points.
- **Good** clients *know* that quality workers demand more than a bare minimum rate.
- **Good** clients customarily find *good* workers and continue to return to those workers in order to maintain a level of quality.
- **Good** clients respect the worker and understand that a business transaction must be beneficial *both* ways.
- **Good** clients openly discuss issues to *solve* them rather than focusing on blame.
- **Good** clients understand rates may increase over a period of time - they understand inflation, cost of living, and other business principles such as this as a "whole" rather than focusing *only* on what they must pay.

---

- **Bad** clients will always shop for the *cheapest* worker they can find.
- **Bad** clients will be slow to pay.
- **Bad** clients generally have issues with scope creep.
- **Bad** clients will only return to hire you again if they feel they got the "better end" of the deal.
- **Bad** clients *never* accept an issue may be on *their* end and almost *always* assume if there's a problem it's the worker's fault.
- **Bad** clients *always* want the same price, or a *better* price -  **if** they happen to return to you. They always argue for discounts, want a "deal", or complain your rates are too high (even if they are remarkably low). They focus on what they are paying, not what they are receiving, your skills, abilities or other things you offer.

---

These are **generalizations**. However, in the $10/hr range you are setting yourself to build a stable of bad, demanding, problematic clients. In all my years of experience, I have **never** run into a **single** client looking for the "cheapest rates" that was anything other than a problem. Now, that is *my* experience. perhaps yours is different. And I *do not* know your region or specific fields. So, things could be different.

In order to build **stable, repeat, long-standing, clients** you need one thing from them -- *loyalty*.

So you need to ask yourself who is more likely to value *your services* and feel more loyal over a period of time - the client paying you $10/hr or the client paying $50/hr?

Or look at it this way... which do you take better care of and value more - the $20 pair of sunglasses you got at the grocery store or the $300 pair of Oakleys sunglasses?

Then ask yourself where you want to be positioned in the market.

Gaining a quality stable of good, return, clients may take some time. However, **I have yet to *ever* see a bad client turn into a good client.** Things just do **not** happen that way.

Anyone bargain shopping and hiring you for $10/hr is going to be a one-off, get it and be done, client. If they *happen* to return to you it will be out of necessity (or cheapness) on their part, not due to any loyalty towards you. And the moment you raise your rates, they will start looking for someone else at $10/hr rather than pay a higher rate.

You can **never** start cheap with a client and expect them to be a long-standing, quality, client. They will customarily balk at each and every rate increase and as soon as they find someone cheaper, they'll drop you like a hot potato.

Again, I don't know your region or current rate trends for *your* specific skill set. But it seems to me, pricing yourself low is *never* a valid business decision unless you *know* you just want *any* work you can get, no matter how *bad* that work or client may be.

In addition, there's some general thought to the industry you are in. If everyone in your specific field is charging $30-$80/hr and you price yourself at $10/hr, you kind of do a disservice to *everyone* in the industry by conveying to the word that the work isn't worth much money. Granted this is a minor, secondary, thought. But if you *ever* want to be making *really good* money, you should keep the industry as a whole in mind and seek to elevate it, not lower it.

Also be aware.. I don't use online services like "upwork" because that's where a lot of bad clients find workers. There are better ways to find quality clients. [How can experienced contractor survive outside Elance/oDesk/Freelancer?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/how-can-experienced-contractor-survive-outside-elance-odesk-freelancer/2849#2849)

> Edit for additional note: I do not know where you are located... but here, the U.S. state minimum wage is currently just above $9/hr -- so at $10/hr your basically saying you essentially have no more skill or experience than **any** random person off the street. Be aware of the message you send with your pricing.

Comment: Amen and yahoo.

Comment: yup.  I'd also add that a client you meet in person or are referred to by somebody you know have a greater chance of being a good client...and longer lasting.  there is a lot of value in a client being able to talk with and sometimes meet their contractor.  charge what you're worth! (especially if you're ok for money while you're in school)

Answer (score 1):

When there is starting , I would prefer your way **A**. Start work at basic rate and increase when you confident and have good relation.

> How to build up long-term clients

1. Be honest always with client
2. Suggest them technical things which save their money and time
3. Provide work delivery on time, Do not miss deadlines
4. Never do over bill when you are working on hour base project
5. Always work with reasonable price
6. Ask them always about your work. For ex : how you are doing , Any improvement needed?

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's great to include general tips, but why specifically would you prefer option A? How is that **the** correct option? Can you [edit] to include the extra info? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to involve the customers in your own history. Ask them a rate corresponding to the value of your work today. Not more, not less.

You will attract and retain customers by understanding their needs, delivering the desired quality and being flexible.

Comment: good points. **be sure to read Harry Cover's first sentence!**