# Getting started as a Qt developer

Tags: programmer

---

Scenario (Skip it if you don't care)

So I currently work for a company in India which takes out-sourced work and hires local devs to work on them. Now, the situation for most cases (including mine) is that said company charges the clients an up-word of $3000 per month and forwards about $900 to the developer. I don't blame them as this is just business and they do provide better stability (such as ability to hire more people; if I leave / if more are required).

Outside of this, the company doesn't provide much. I am managed by the client's team, and even my workstation is sponsored by said client. Now getting to it, I wish to cut out the middle-man and maybe get $1500 instead.

---

I am a Qt/C++ programmer with about 4 years of experience under my belt. Now I wish to work on my own. My problem is my lack of exposure to diverse technologies (zero web development experience / interest). Mostly, I work on front-end or back end logic development.

I was reading [Getting started as a freelance programmer](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/getting-started-as-a-freelance-programmer), but I noticed the manner for starting is hinted at find a whale. Now there's the problem, I don't know how. Also, I do lack the confidence to project time-lines. Not to mention I don't know how to stand out in a large group of other devs (even if I provide work for free originally).

I'm also concerned if what I'm looking for is contract work instead of freelance work as I prefer to work on one project at a time.

As Scott (Thanks for pointing it out before it was closed) mentioned, I should add a proper question here;

1. Considering my lack of experience in web tech, am I acting per-maturely on trying to get into freelancing?
2. Is there scope for long projects in Qt while freelancing?
3. Would working for a single project be considered freelancing or contractual work?
4. How can I enrich my description so as to attract more customers to me?  I mean what are they (employers) looking for and how can I readily make the info of my being able to deliver available to them?

---

Sorry about the rant, but I wasn't sure how to structure this question.

Comment: Was there a question? This is exceptionally broad without any targeted question. You seem familiar enough with the Stack model to understand questions need to be objective in nature.

Comment: good point, I'll reduce the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try my best to cover all the points.

- First of all, focus on your skills and polish them. You can always get work if you have good skills.
- Secondly, everyone starts as a beginner in freelancing. So there's no need to worry if you don't have any industry experience. You can still start working as a freelancer.
- Create profiles that can attract customers and add skills to which you have the best command.
- Keep pricing low at the start. Once you start getting clients you can increase it then.
- Regarding writing a description for your profile, you can take help from the freelancers' profiles that are doing good on freelancing platforms and can write a great description. You can also find some examples of how to write freelancing profiles on the Internet.
- And you can find any caliber of projects over freelancing platforms and can choose the one that suits you the best.

I hope these points help you. If still any queries, feel free to ask.

Comment: I don't intend on working in web-tech. I am good at Qt and wish to continue in this field. Could you please describe the scope for Qt freelancers? Most of the successful guys post their freelance experience to draw more customers. Something I don't have.

Comment: There are multiple Qt related jobs on freelancing platforms and you can easily get a job if you are good at that. So to gain experience as a Qt freelancer just start with low pricing and offer good services to clients.

Comment: @Bhoot if still any queries, please feel free to ask. :)

Comment: No, nothing more. I was hoping to figure out a way to make my brand quickly, but seems like I'll have to start from the bottom and work my way up slowly.