# How to get work on freelancer.com as an existing contractor but new to freelancer.com?

Tags: freelance-websites, group-freelancing

I have been on freelancer for the past 4 months, and I have been continuously applying for jobs.  I did not hear back from any client. We have done couple of work, and I listed my portfolio on my freelancer as well as on my Web site.

Still due to no work done on freelancer, no one is hiring us. Can you please suggest the points I should take care to get hired?

I have applied to around 7 to 8 projects a week for the last 4 months. I tried to provide best lowest bid for the same, but still I didn't get contacted by any of the clients.

Can any one help me specifying how should I write a cover letter or message to client to get contacted by the employer?

As a freelancer who is new to freelancer.com, how can I maximize my chances of landing a contract?

Comment: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site

Comment: Hi Blaze, welcome to Freelancing SE. Take a look at the link Peter shared. If that doesn't help, you may want to consider an [edit] to make this a more specific question. Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253 I have edited my question. I am sorry but can i know why everyone down vote my question ?

Comment: Hi Blaze, the question *was* too broad for our format, but don't take it personally. The voting mechanism is intended to push the best content to the top of the page. Take a look at [help - topic](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] for some more info on what our site is about. Our  goal is to become a resource of knowledge for freelancing. With that said, your edits significantly improved the question, so I'll take it off hold. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Blaze-Core Have you read that link? It will help you. At least you will understand that the lowest bid will not work with serious clients. Just rate your work, make an EXCELLENT+++ profile and give such offer that you will be satisfied with such money. This way, you will be rejected 10 times, but 11th client will like you. Anyone of us here, who tried working lowest bid, got burnt in the end.

Comment: @PeterMV yes, I have read, I will try my best thanks for your supports.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be to start with a 20-30$ project and offer it to do for 10$.
If you are able to do  the project according to the clients needs,hopefully he will give you the 5 star rating

That's how you get the start.

And secondly when you apply for the job make sure you just don't say that you have experience in blah blah fields etc.No one is interested to hear about your qualifications,they want real work,so instead just show them   links to the screenshots of the similar work you have done in that field.......

Comment: Do you have any citations to back that later statement up? I've found that the fact I have 8 years of experience in server administration (and 6 in development) kinda helps way more than saying "Yeah, I can do anything. No need to see proof; just give me money".

Comment: @Santa i don't see how your comment is related to my question.

Comment: All i am saying is,just show the guy "similar" projects,nothing else ......