# How to start working in freelancer

Tags: programmer

I am an IT student and I know some programming languages. I want to do projects in freelancer. But I dont know how to start , how to get projects from others. First the employer might check my profile whether to give me the project or not. But I am just starting to work so how can I have a good profile in freelancer.

Comment: Hi Viper, welcome to Freelancing! This question is too broad, and is not a good fit here. Try to specialize in *ONE* question, per question. You can easily ask other questions and maybe even link here. A good question shows that you've tried some things, and need help because you hit a hiccup. Feel free to [edit] your post to improve it. As well, read [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Hi Viper, you might also take a look at [How do I get my first job at a freelancing site?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site).

Comment: You can get a basic idea from the site: http://webindream.com/freelance-how-start-freelance/ 
and 
http://webindream.com/freelance-how-did-i-start/

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Software Engineering student, and first thing you do, make yourself an online portfolio. Showcase your skills. As a student you will have a lot of projects, add them on as you progress in your course. If your skills are good, hardly you'll have any project that wouldn't be worth showing. 
In regards to how to get projects. It depends on what area of IT you want to freelance in. IT is a very broad term. When I was doing Web Design, I went door-to-door offering my services to various businesses in town.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I want to do programming for freelancing, mainly java programming

Comment: You should sign up to various freelancer sites. I personally like peopleperhour.com but there are many (elance, freelancer.net and so on)

Comment: I want to do programming for freelancing, mainly java programming. And as you are a software engineer, I have a question for you. I am curious in it. What's the difference between project management and software engineering. I think project management will need less technical skills but software engineering will need more technical knowledge

Comment: @viper: I'd like to give you a long answer but it would not be an answer to your original question so I will not. For a start, a simple search on Google would give you an answer in a matter of seconds anyways. Best of luck!

Comment: I would be glad if you message me if you the things that you want to say

Answer (score 3):

First of all, search for some internship to a company (a place where you give your time in exchange for the opportunity to gain knowledge and real life experience).

Why do this?

It will open many doors. You will meet people, you will have what to write in your CV and what to show when some one ask's for your portfolio.

In meanwhile, hustle; search for jobs in newspapers, on the internet or ask your friends.

Not for last, make a habit of speaking about you as working in the given area of IT. Example: if you plan writing Java applications or games or mobile apps, when you speak about yourself to strangers say "I do mobile applications".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I am working as an intern in an organization as a java programmer. But its hard to manage time for the college studies.

Comment: I know is hard but, remember this; you need social integration. You need to know the right people and stay connected to the real day-to-day job environment. If you isolate yourself for sure you will have more time or you will believe it's easier but on the long run you will have more to lose. Another thing, be as present as you can on the job. Take responsibilities, help anyone, do as much as possible. You will see, rewards will come soon.