# what to keep in mind before starring a free lancing work?

Tags: group-freelancing

I am a open source developer , and i want to start free lancing work in my field. i want to know that what things to keep in mind when you are going to start your free lancing work?

Comment: Hi Mayank, welcome to Freelancing SE. I recommend you read some basic information on getting started (or even do a search for that here as others have likely already asked this). Then, if you have a more specific question about where you're confused, ask that. Our Q&A site works best for questions that aren't overly broad. Hope this helps!

Comment: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site