# Can online bidding for projects work without prior record?

Tags: freelance-websites, project-bidding

Someone told me that if I want to get or deal with projects by online bidding, it would be necessary to show previous bidding records. For example, you must have dealt with at least 2-3 projects before.

To me, it seems akin to new candidates applying for jobs and each company saying that they don't hire new candidates; come back once you've gained experience.

Is it *really* possible to get or deal projects via online bidding?

Comment: No need to shout (with capital letters). There are some good advise here http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site

Answer (score 3):

Don't listen to people who have no clue what they are talking about!

Now, everyone and each of us started as a new guy, either in some field or on some freelance service. As everyone, you will also start by working day by day, step by step. First projects will be small money and with experience you will get more money.

So if you expect $10k the first month, I will tell you that it's impossible. If you expect to earn $10k a month after 1 year, then I would say it's possible.

Start with a service you are expert in, be honest and hard working, treat the client like the most beautiful girl and success will come in time.

PS. You have try to learn Internet ethics firstly. Like capital letters mean shouting.