# No response after project bid

Tags: freelance-websites, project-bidding

I am new to freelancing. I joined a freelance site today and made a bid on a project relating to iOS social media integration (since I have good knowledge on the subject). I also based my bid on the description, but I haven't gotten a response.

How do I know who is selected for a project, and would I get a response (even if I don't get the bid)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my first job at a freelancing site?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site)

Comment: Something to keep in mind: grammar and spelling are _very_ important when writing project bids. If the bid that you've made uses similar grammar to that in this question, then frankly, I'd reject the bid outright without sending a reply. I've edited the question to what I think you were trying to ask ("Should I get a response? Can I find out who won the bid?"), but please keep attention to detail in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You may not get a response if you are not selected.  Depending on the site, there may be a way for you to see who, if anyone, is selected.

I use eLance to hire people sometimes and it used to be set up so that you could click to turn down people, and it gave you reasons to pick from (Like too expensive, preferred another method, did not address issue, etc.)  But now I notice there is no way to contact the bidders unless you go into each one and send them a private message.  I feel bad just ignoring people but I figure that's the way it is set up now and the people bidding understand that.  That is eLance.  I don't know about other freelance sites.

Regardless, I would not expect a response within a day.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the freelance site. It's quite common for buyers not to communicate with all bidders, especially for bids that they don't intend to use.

It's also common for buyers to NEVER select a bidder (one reason I stopped using eLance as a source for work).

I believe most freelance sites will have a status indicating if the project was awarded and indicate which bidder won the project.

A day is too soon to expect a response (unless there is a time-critical element to the bid).

Answer (score 1):

If you are new, it's likely that you do not have any "Reputation", "Ratings", "Reviews" or "Portfolio" to show. As such, many buyers won't even consider selecting you... Even if your bid $ is very attractive. Reason being many buyers have came across 'cheats' or 'incompetent' project bidders who simply don't deliver the work requested. It's a total waste of the buyers' time.

I would suggest that you build up your "Reputation", "Ratings", "Reviews" or "Portfolio" along the way while you are bidding for projects. Drop the buyers note that you are new to freelancing but not new in your industry and have xx years of experience and is willing to take their project at a lower than usual bid so as to build your portfolio. And ask for their chance for you to proof yourself as a worthy freelancer.