# What are the best websites for freelance jobs?

Tags: freelance-websites

I'm relatively new to online jobs and stuff, I have already started to make accounts on the freelance websites I know about, like LinkedIn, Sourceforge Jobs, and some local sites.
And in my field of interest which is graphic design I've got Behance, graphicriver. as a way to show online portfolio.
My question is, what are the most reputable websites for freelance jobs?

Comment: IMO, there are no "best" places, but more like more reputable, or have more jobs posted in certain sites or are concentrated on certain areas of expertise. Freelancer.com is another if you haven't been there yet. You'll figure out which one(s) is/are best for "you".

Comment: There are lot of websites available. I like `upwork.com` , `peopleperhour.com`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my first job at a freelancing site?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site)

Comment: Hi Lenin, welcome to Freelancing.SE! Unfortunately, asking polling questions such as this is not a good format for a Q&A network such as the Stack Exchange, and has been closed as such. If you can, [edit] your question to show what you have tried, why it hasn't worked, and how to solve a *problem*, as opposed to asking for a list of sites.