# 6yrs of experience in Portfolio Management

Tags: group-freelancing

I have six of experience in portfolio management n currently working for one of best Bank on the same project. I'm ready to train people on portfolio management n quants. But I m not getting any leads... I registered myself self on several pay sites as well. Kindly help how I can grow my freelancing business.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my first job at a freelancing site?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get clients, you must go where the clients are - or at least where they are looking for you.

It seems reasonable to assume that (investment) banks do not seek training of the sort you wish to offer on internet portals. They probably get these services from consultancies that also cover many other of their business needs.

If you are not already working as a trainer, you could perhaps approach your current job/client and propose this service. A rejection would probably not sour the relationship from their part - so that seems risk-free.

If you are already a freelance trainer, but finding it difficult to find new clients, you could perhaps contact companies which deliver external consultants to banks. Big companies tend not to hire individual freelancers - unless they are already known.